# When creating a launcher item in 15.04, what is the significance of quotes in the file path?

Tags: unity, 15.04, launcher, icons

I'm trying to make an icon for Sublime Text 2. When I use the settings below I get "There was an error launching the application"

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Sublime Text
Type=Application
Exec=/home/aortiz49/Application Data/Sublime_Text_2/sublime_text
Terminal=false
Icon=/home/aortiz49/Application Data/Sublime_Text_2/Icon/256x256/sublime_text.png
Comment=Sublime Text 2
NoDisplay=false
Catergories=Development
Name[en]=Sublime
```

However, when I put the Exec path in double quotes like this:

`"/home/aortiz49/Application Data/Sublime_Text_2/sublime_text"`

The application works.

But if I put double quotes on the Icon path, the Icon disappears.

What difference do double quotes have when specifying a path to something?
I know they're used when specifying paths with spaces in them but these paths don't have spaces.

Comment: Sure they do. Look at the path again. There's a space between `Application` and `Data`.

Comment: @terdon unlike what you would think, in a .desktop file, in the icon path, a space *should not* be escaped! In the Exec= line, it should though.

Comment: @JacobVlijm I know, but the OP mentioned that quoting it fixes the exec issue and was wondering why since there are no spaces in the path.

Comment: @terdon There *are* spaces in the  `exec` path, OP even mentions: *However, when I put the Exec path in double quotes like this: The application works.* which is correct.

Comment: @JacobVlijm read the last sentence: "What difference do double quotes have when specifying a path to something? I know they're used when specifying paths with spaces in them **but these paths don't have spaces.**" That's what I was replying to.

Comment: @terdon Ah, sorry, sorry, I misunderstood.

Comment: @Aort49 Was this the kind of answer you were looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but these paths don't have spaces.

The path have a space between `Application` and `Data`.
Therefore you need the double quotes or a backslash `\`:

```
Exec=/"home/aortiz49/Application Data/Sublime_Text_2/sublime_text"
```

or

```
Exec=/home/aortiz49/Application\ Data/Sublime_Text_2/sublime_text
```

---

And for `Icon`:

```
Icon=/home/aortiz49/"Application Data"/Sublime_Text_2/Icon/256x256/sublime_text.png
```

Comment: Almost holiday here :)

Answer (score 1):

Unlike what you would think, in a `.desktop` file, a space:

***should not*** be escaped in the icon path, so:

```
Icon=/home/aortiz49/Application Data/Sublime_Text_2/Icon/256x256/sublime_text.png
```

is ok, but a space:

***should*** be escaped in the `Exec=` line, so:

```
Exec=/home/aortiz49/Application Data/Sublime_Text_2/sublime_text
```

is incorrect. It should be:

```
Exec=/home/aortiz49/"Application Data"/Sublime_Text_2/sublime_text
```

The reason is that the `Exec=` line represents *a command*, which will interpret what comes after the space as an argument, while the line `Icon=` represents *a path* to the icon.